# Magento add Sub attribute to attribute?

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

I need to add a sub attribute into some attribute in magento, am novice to Magneto ,

For example

(Material)Attribute Group
  Blue
   -- Dark blue
   -- Navy blue
  Pink
   -- baby pink
   -- dark pink

please let me know this is possible am loosing my confidence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Dependent attributes ( Means an attribute has different Options for other attribute )

For instance Cloths colors and Sizes,

You can do this by

- Create Configurable products with main attribute ( Color )
- Create some simple products with Different Size values and quantities
- Assign those simple products to the main configurable product  ( from associated products tab in the Main Configurable product )

This way when you see the options it will be the way you want it

Comment: So try to follow the steps above and let me know the result ?

Comment: Great i have worked like above and got the exact result. Thank you so much.